# Custom button to create a new record

Tags: javascript, custom-button

How to create a Custom button to create a new record in other object?

I tried by using javascript code to create a new record i am getting:

> Unexpected token error

my code is

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var curnc= new sforce.Sobject(TR_Currency_Approval__c); 
curnc.currency={!TR_Currency__c.CurrencyIsoCode}; 
curnc.Active__c={!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}; 
curnc.Description__c={!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}; 

result=sforce.connection.create.([curnc]); 

if(result[0].success == 'true'){ 
alert('An New Currency Approval with Name - ' + curnc.currency + ' was Created Successfully.'); 
}
```

is there any other way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- Enclose the values in quotes
- Declare `result` as a variable and remove the dot after create:
- Maybe need to correct the SObject method (capitalisation)

```javascript
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var curnc= new sforce.SObject(TR_Currency_Approval__c); 
curnc.currency='{!TR_Currency__c.CurrencyIsoCode}'; 
curnc.Active__c='{!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}'; 
curnc.Description__c='{!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}'; 

var result=sforce.connection.create([curnc]); 

if(result[0].success == 'true'){ 
alert('An New Currency Approval with Name - ' + curnc.currency + ' was Created Successfully.'); 
}
```

Comment: No dot after create

Comment: Thanks Fernando,not working after removing the dot also

Comment: @prasadnagamalli I just spotted a few more errors and updated the answer. Take a look =D

Comment: did the changes you suggested, but issue was not resolved fernando

Comment: Is the message still unexpected token error?